# I am trying to represent the value of gender field with 'male' if 1 and 'female' is 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Need to convert gender field has data type as bit.

I used this syntax:

```
Select case when CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit)=1 then 'Male' 
when CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit)=0 then 'Female' 
else  CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit) 
end
```

Returns the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Male' to data type bit.

Comment: If "gender field has data type as bit" why are you casting it to bit?

Comment: What is the type of `GenderIsMale`?

Comment: Your question was about type conversion, but it is worth asking: is a bit field the best way to store "gender"? SQL does allow NULLs in a bit field, so that at least gives you a third value, perhaps for "unknown" or "declined to state". Not sure exactly what your DB is for, but you might need to also allow for people who identify as "non-binary", i.e., neither male or female. There are a variety of ways people might identify, including genderqueer,

Comment: @BradC this would easily include the Pakistani/Indian concept of Hijra/Aravani/Aruvani/Jagappa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender. What the OP needs to consider is that the proper field is "biological sex" or "legally recognized sex" or "chromosomal sex" which ARE STILL not binary choices. There's also XXY, XXX, etc. This should be a text field, which makes the issue that the question asker is trying a lot easier to define. Also, this sounds like it is best left to application logic, not database logic.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have two different return types, depending on the value of `[GenderIsMale]`; the two `WHEN` conditions return a string while the `ELSE` returns a `BIT`. It is easier to see if you format the code nicely:

```
Select case
    when CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit)=1 then 'Male'   -- return type = VARCHAR
    when CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit)=0 then 'Female' -- return type = VARCHAR
    else CAST([GenderIsMale] AS bit)                 -- return type = BIT
end
```

You can test this as follows:

```
DECLARE @GenderIsMale INT = 1;

Select case
    when CAST(@GenderIsMale AS bit)=1 then 'Male'
    when CAST(@GenderIsMale AS bit)=0 then 'Female'
    else CAST(@GenderIsMale AS bit)
end
```

Returns:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Male' to data type bit.

You can fix this by returning a string (or literal `NULL`) in the `ELSE` condition (pick one of those `ELSE` conditions, depending on what you are trying to accomplish):

```
SELECT CASE CAST([GenderIsMale] AS BIT)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Male'
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Female'
    ELSE 'other string'
    --ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [GenderIsMale]) -- if column is a numeric type
    --ELSE [GenderIsMale] -- if column is a string type
    --ELSE NULL
END;
```

**Please note:**

- Depending on the datatype of the `GenderIsMale` column and the data in it, it is possible that there is an additional source of the error: the `CAST` of the value into `BIT`. For example, if the datatype is `VARCHAR`, then values of empty string, `'true'`, `'false'`, and strings of just digits 0 - 9 (no spaces, commas, periods, or minus sign) will convert, but anything else will error. Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can switch to using `TRY_CAST` (or even `TRY_CONVERT`) to get around that.
- The commented-out `ELSE` conditions are mainly to show the possible variations for getting the resulting expression to be consistent across all branches of the `CASE` statement. But in the scenario here of having a `BIT` / boolean value, if the datatype of the `GenderIsMale` column is a number, then the only value that could fall through to the `ELSE` is a `NULL`, hence you would use `ELSE NULL`. But if the datatype is a string, then you would use `ELSE [GenderIsMale]`.